# How to collapse rows with same identifier and retain non-empty column values?

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyr

I have a table that (after some initial processing) has multiple rows with the same main identifier but with different column values (either 0 or a value > 0).

**Example table**
*with main identifier "produce"*

```
df = data.frame(produce = c("apples","apples", "bananas","bananas"),
                grocery1=c(0,1,1,1),
                grocery2=c(1,0,1,1),
                grocery3=c(0,0,1,1))


###########################

> df
  produce grocery1 grocery2 grocery3
1  apples        0        1        0
2  apples        1        0        0
3 bananas        1        1        1
4 bananas        1        1        1
```

I'd like to collapse (or merge?) rows with the same identifier and retain the non-empty (here, any nonzero values) values in each column

**Example desired output**

```
 shopping grocery1 grocery2 grocery3
1   apples        1        1        0
2  bananas        1        1        1
```

Is there a simple function or piping in *tidyverse* that I am missing and that can handle this?

Comment: `dplyr::group_by()` plus `dplyr::summarise()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using base R `aggregate` we can do

```
aggregate(.~produce, df, function(x) +any(x > 0))

#  produce grocery1 grocery2 grocery3
#1  apples        1        1        0
#2 bananas        1        1        1
```

---

Or using `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
  group_by(produce) %>%
  summarise_all(~+any(. > 0))

#  produce grocery1 grocery2 grocery3
#  <fct>      <int>    <int>    <int>
#1 apples         1        1        0
#2 bananas        1        1        1
```

---

and same with `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, lapply(.SD, function(x) +any(x > 0)), by=produce]
```

Comment: Thank you! Manipulating tables aren't yet intuitive for me (whether inside or outside the tidyverse) .... hopefully more cycles here and on my own will change this.

Comment: Isn't this just applying `max` as an aggregate function?

Comment: hmmm..didn't think it that way. Maybe you are right, re-reading the question I am not clear about objective of the OP and what would they expect as output if there is any value > 1.

Answer (score 1):

We can use `max`

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
   group_by(produce) %>% 
   summarise_all(max)
# A tibble: 2 x 4
#  produce grocery1 grocery2 grocery3
#  <fct>      <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl>
#1 apples         1        1        0
#2 bananas        1        1        1
```